# If statement using time format in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, math, time, cell

I'm trying to set up something in excel where in cell F4 is a calculated time, in the format of something like this: 9:30:00. (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)
Cell e8 is a static number that never changes, unless you manually change the cell lets say it's set as 10.

I am trying to set up a cell that looks at call f4, checks if its under 9:00:00 and if it is then times cell e8 by cell f4, if it's over 9 simply times cell e8 by a static number of 8.

my current code is t working,

=IF(f4>9:00, e8*9, e8*f4)

Comment: what do you want to see?  9 minutes times 8, so the result is 72:00:00?

Comment: I want to see an output of an integer so, e8 is 10 and lets say f4 is 9:30:00 it'd trigger the if statement to output 90, as 10*9=90. If f4 was 6:30:00 it'd give 10*6.5=65

Comment: if you have 1:09:36, whta do you want as your answer?

Comment: You know google has this answer with minimal search effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any meaning when you multiply time value?

Regardless, assuming that your `F4` contains time data, like `8:00` or `9:25`, use this:

```
=IF(F4>TIME(9,0,0),E8*9,E8*F4)
```

Comment: This worked thank you, will accept as answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: Quick question, not sure if I should start up a new one or ask here. Is there a way to detect how much over "9:00:00" f4 is, so lets say it's 9:30:00, 30 minutes over 9:00:00 the output is 0:30:00?